# eliminate documents and an electronic database

Tags: word-choice

I am puzzled about the word choice, namely the verb "to eliminate". Can we say that the person eliminated documents or an electronic database because they were of no use anymore or outdated.

If no, which word is natural to native English speakers in this context?

Comment: For electronic documents, *delete* is the commom term, but *eliminate* also works. So does *destroy.* Is there a specific context in which you found the phrase? That might help clear up why the writer chose *eliminate.* For paper documents, *delete* would not normally be used.

Comment: A CFO or department head might decide to eliminate a particular program, and there it would mean that employees should stop using the program, not the act of physically removing the program and data files from the computer.  But you can also say, this file should be eliminated from your hard drive.

Comment: I'm so tempted to poke in the word 'obviate' here, as a tangent.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of computers or any electronic devices, we *generally* use *deleted* or in *rare* cases, *erased*. The wide use of this word is probably due to the 'key' we have on the keyboard 'Delete', and also as an option when the files are selected.

As exactly defined in [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/delete)

> delete: to remove something that has been written or printed, or that has been stored on ***a computer***

However, if the context is not computers or devices, 'destroyed' comes to my mind as I have read it plenty of times while talking about 'documents' or 'files'. Eliminate/terminate kind of words for literature/papers are less frequent or at least natives *might* not use it.